# Json schema validate property name in array

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have this json object

```
{
  "status": 68,
  "error": [
    {
      "description_ru": "Ошибка авторизации. Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность введенных e-mail и пароля."
    },
    {
      "description_en": "Authorization error. Please check login and password."
    }
  ]
}
```

And i write next json schema

```
{
  "title": "Неверно указан пароль",
  "type": "object",
  "properties":{
    "status":{
      "description": "Статус операции",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "error":{
      "description":"Информация об ошибке на разных языках",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "properties":{
          "description_ru":{
            "description": "Информация об ошибке на русском языке",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description_en":{
            "description": "Информация об ошибке на английском языке",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required":["status", "error"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I have a next problem. If i change name in json schema **error** to **error-edited** and run validation, then i get next error:

> false Property error does not exist in the schema

Ok, it's perfect!

However, if I change property name inside array error in json schema **description_en** to ***description_en-edited** and run validation, then i don't get the error.

Please tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "error" is required but "description_en" is not.

Add "additionalProperties" to the object in the items:

```
...
"items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "description_ru":{
        "description": "Информация об ошибке на русском языке",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "description_en":{
        "description": "Информация об ошибке на английском языке",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
"minItems": 2
...
```

Comment: Ok, i make this schema your advice:
https://jsfiddle.net/u3751gsn/
And this method doesnt work.

Please if you can, use this online validator https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You are right, I didn't look at the json data carefully. In your case description_en and description_ru are not required, you use one or the other so they are optionall. I updated the response, I think now you will get what you expected.

Comment: Hello Pedro!
Thanks you for help! Your solution will solve my problem fully if you specify Number of the array elements **"minItems":2**, please add it in you answer, and i accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks, you Pedro!